# Session variables lost in Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, session-variables

This is the contents of my php file:

```
<?php   
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION); 
 ?>
```

Why in chrome do I see empty session values and in other browsers I can correctly see them?

Comment: So i've just noticed using WWW. actually unsets the sessions! :S

Comment: Please view related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247842/session-data-lost-in-chrome-only