# Cookies and Sessions deleted in Chrome

Tags: session, cookies

I'm facing an issue with my Sessions and Cookies. I have a landing page in which I create a Session and cookies. After redirecting to another page, all my sessions and cookies are deleted in Chrome but in other actions it doesn't occur.

A few things that i saw in my logs:

1. In chrome I can see that the code access the Session_Start event in Global.asax.cs one more time during the process but in IE it access the event only once at the begining.
2. Another thing, our landing pages unlike other pages, doesn't inherit a MasterPage but the page that I'm redirecting to, does inherit a master page.
3. Could that be a dis-synchronization in our Load Balancer between the servers?

Comment: Possible reason could be favicon handling in Chrome http://stackoverflow.com/a/10818694/466677