# Session variable empty after page reload

Tags: php, session-variables

Only one of my many session variables on the cart page of my e-commerce application is getting destroyed somehow. When i add the product to the cart along with a session id, it creates an order_id(using some hash and salt logic) and puts it in session variable and when i go to the cart page it queries the DB based on both order_id and session id to fetch the products in the cart. For the first time it fetches the records, but immediately after it if i reload the page it gets an empty order_id. I'm pulling my hair on this as to how only one of the session variables is getting flushed.

**It is happening on the web-server only but works totally fine on localhost**

My `add_to_cart.php` (Session Logic)

```
if(empty($_SESSION['sessid'])){
    $_SESSION['sessid'] = session_id();
}

    $user_sessid = $_SESSION['sessid'];

  $ip = get_ip_address();



 if(empty($_SESSION['order_id'])){

    $ip = get_ip_address();
    $with_time = strtotime("now");
    $addsalt = substr(md5($ip.uniqid($with_time,true)),0,15);
    $_SESSION['order_id'] = $addsalt;
}

 $order_id = $_SESSION['order_id'];
```

My `cart.php` (Session Logic Only)

```
 $user_sessid = $_SESSION['sessid'];
 $order_id = $_SESSION['order_id'];

 $userid = $_SESSION['user_id'];

 if(empty($userid)){

 $r_type = 1;   

 $q1=<<<SQL
select od.ipaddress, od.modified_ts, od.product_id,od.discount,od.quantity,p.id,p.name,p.price, p.img_dir,p.img_name from orders od, products p where od.order_id='$order_id' and od.user_sessid='$user_sessid' and od.product_id = p.id
 SQL;

} else {
$r_type = 2;

  $q1=<<<SQL
select uc.modified_ts, uc.product_id,uc.discount,uc.quantity,p.id,p.name,p.price, p.img_dir,p.img_name from user_cart uc, products p where uc.userid='$userid' and uc.product_id = p.id
  SQL;


}

 $r1=$db->query($q1);
 $num1 = $r1->num_rows;
```

When i'm echoing out the query on immediate reload of the cart page it is getting an empty `order_id`.

I'm wondering my head off as to how this weird thing is happening. Please help...

**Update** I am including a file on top of both the pages which has `session_start` on top of it and therefore it explains the user_sessid being created and used.

Comment: `session_start()` is missing on every page. - http://php.net/manual/de/function.session-start.php

Comment: Is this problem in every browser or only in Chrome? If it is related to chrome make sure you include the favicon.

Comment: @Perry i thought of this but it is giving the same thing in firefox as well.

Comment: @Perry favicon?? eh?? how could that create a problem if at all that's the case

Comment: you need to check session variables...

Comment: Could we possibly see the contents of the file you're including that starts your sessions? Is it the same file executing in the same way for both pages?

Comment: @coder101 I had once a problem with session to, the thing was it only happend in chrome.Chrome couldn't find the favicon and because of that the response was a 404. see this post for more information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247842/session-data-lost-in-chrome-only

Comment: @dartacus In the `add_to_cart.php` a file named `functions.php` is included which has `session_start` and in `cart.php`, a file named `header.php` is included which in turn has `functions.php` included in it. And, i'm wondering why everyone is asking the same thing when i've clearly mentioned that only one variable is beings flushed, others i can use very normally.

Comment: @coder101 can you add this to your code: `echo session_id(); print_r($_SESSION)`

Comment: @Perry but it is happening with firefox as well.

Comment: @coder101 We're all asking the same thing because it's good practice to look at *all* of the code involved in an issue. It could be something as simple as a typo - I've had that happen dozens of times. We want to help but can't if we can't see the whole thing.

Comment: @coder101 I know it was just a explantion why the favicon was the problem in chrome.

Comment: @Perry I added the code that you gave and printed out the session array, so the immediate access of the cart page after adding a product gives order_id in the session array but then when i refresh the page it is removed from the array but other session variables are well within the array

Comment: @coder101 that is strange, it looks like your are resetting the order_id some how. Do you have some were in your code unset or something like that?

Comment: I'm only unsetting the order_id on the logout page but not when the user is not logged in. And as i said, the only flow is adding to cart and after that viewing the cart page which destroys the orderid on reload.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add `session_start()` to the top of the file.

Edit:
You said you were querying on the session id and order id, but you also have

```
and od.product_id = p.id
```

at the end of your query. Where is this logic? I'm guessing that you are using a $_GET request or something similar to determine the product ID. Maybe this has something to do with your issue, possibly just remove it from the query? You should only need to use 1 unique key for your SQL query, especially as unique as the hash you're creating.

Comment: Well, no offence but i do know that and i'm including the functions file on both the pages which has `session_start` on top of it and which explains the session_id not emptying.

Comment: @coder101 I wasn't thinking that you didn't know, I just didn't see it as part of the code.

Comment: `and od.product_id = p.id` is being used to group the products in the results fetched and i'm simply joining the two tables with the product_id hence this part. but how do you explain that only one session variable is getting destroyed and not all of them

Answer (score 0):

An obvious point, but check you're definitely calling session_start() on both pages?