# Server "times out" after opening a file

Tags: .net, google-chrome

So I have a .Net based CMS site.
When clicking around everything works smoothly as expected.
BUT, after opening any media such as a pdf file or a image directly (e.g:  www.mysite.com/media/mydoc.pdf) any succeeding request times out or atleast takes forever. Up to 2 minutes.

Also note this only happens in Chrome. It seems to happen for a lot of people not only me and from different locations.

Comment: I have done some further investigation. If I remove the ASP.NET Session Id cookie AFTER accessing the static file, The site keeps running smoothly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the error. 
We have placed the favicon in a img-folder. While this works fine when surfing to a page it renders a 404 when surfing static-files since chrome always looks for a favicon even when loading static files.
As described in the answer here: [Session data lost in Chrome only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247842/session-data-lost-in-chrome-only)

The 404 request somehow altered the session cookie.

By adding an extra favicon to the root of the site this case was solved.