# TempData gets cleared after RedirectToAction method call. Session is also empty. I am using ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: session, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, tempdata, redirecttoaction

I have a problem with TempData in MVC5. I know that I can use TempData in the request sequence.
However, after I do RedirectToAction, my TempData as well as Session is empty. I am using owin identity configuration. I think that there is something wrong with my Session configuration. But I don't know where to look for that configuration.

I'll share some code examples. Maybe I am doing something wrong and you can help me with that.

So, I have a ParliamentController.cs. Inside that controller I have methods:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Politicians()
{
      var publishInfo = TempData["Info"];
      var sessionInfo = Session["Info"];

      return View(new Config());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PublishConfig()
{      
      TempData["Info"] = "publish error";
      Session["Info"] = "session info";
      return RedirectToAction("Politicians", "Parliament", new { area = "Admin" });
}
```

Also, I have a Politicians.cshtml

Which has this markup:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PublishConfig", "Parliament", FormMethod.Post, new { area = "Admin" }))
{
      <input type="submit" value="Publish config"/>
}
```

And here are some pictures of debugging:

[image: Method post]
[image: Method get with empy TempData and Session]

Any help would be appreciated. If you need more details just let me know.

**Update:**
Seems like the issue is only reproducible for Google Chrome browser. Although, an incognito mode in google chrome works well.

**I think I've found a solution.**
The problem was in http protocol. I've tried under the https and everything works as expected.
This article helped me to find a solution https://www.petefreitag.com/item/857.cfm

Comment: Funny thing. Seems like it works in incognito mode in Chrome.

Comment: Everything works in Opera standard mode.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247842/session-data-lost-in-chrome-only