# bigcommerce app Session is not working on chrome browser

Tags: php, google-chrome, session, bigcommerce

I am worried, I just found that my PHP sessions are not working in Chrome. Actually, I am working on a Bigcommerce app development so I face the problem. It is working fine in Firefox, internet explores but not in Chrome.

Comment: [hope it will be helpful to you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247842/session-data-lost-in-chrome-only/12614464#12614464)

Comment: Aniket, since the issue is only occurring in your Chrome browser, have you tried clearing out the cache and cookies and giving it another try?

Comment: I have cleared Chrome browser history and cookies but not store data in the session.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in the .htaccess file working fine

```
<ifmodule mod_headers.c>
Header always edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;SameSite=None;Secure
</ifmodule>
```