# Flask session not persisting on chromium browser, session cookie is not created

Tags: python, session, cookies, flask

Following this tutorial piece from [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/#sessions):

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    if 'username' in session:
        return 'Logged in as %s' % escape(session['username'])
    return 'You are not logged in'

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        session['username'] = request.form['username']
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return '''
        <form action="" method="post">
            <p><input type=text name=username>
            <p><input type=submit value=Login>
        </form>
    '''
```

I cannot seem to get this working on Chromium browser. Seems like the session is not being saved and even with `session.modified = True` it does not persist to `index` route. In other words - the session cookie is not being created.

Chromium version: 54.0.2840.71
Tested working on Firefox and Qutebrowser browsers.

Comment: to find out its a chromium side problem, check developer console of chromium browser ( F12 ) & network tab; check the response header contains atlease "Set-Cookie"

Comment: tested on MacOS El Capitan  with Chrome 54.0.2840.98 and on Linux(Ubuntu 16.04) with chromium 56.0.2924.14 (chrome-dev) without any problem. You might have a strange setting on your chrome about sessions  or try updating chromium

Comment: Do you have any other routes defined?  It may be related to favicon.ico.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953536/randomly-losing-session-variables-only-in-google-chrome-url-rewriting

Answer (score 3):

It is to late do add something in this post? I hope not.

I've been fought this problem for a week and find out that is possible to create session in the Chrome browser using IP.

My config file has these configurations:

```
    SERVER_NAME = '192.168.0.6:5000'
    SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = '192.168.0.6:5000'
    SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = '192.168.0.6:5000'
```

It allowed me to use a local virtual machine and the cookie worked perfectly on Chrome, without the need o a local FQDN.

In my case the problem was that the Chrome and Chromium did not create a cookie to connect with the server session.