# How and When does Phalcon framework create new session file?

Tags: session, phalcon

My project information:

- Phalcon framework
- PHP 7.2
- PHP [vlucas/phpdotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv)

My page loses all session (shopping cart, user login...) when page redirects from E-xact Gateway after customer did purchasing. This issues didn't happen before. It happened after integrating phpdotenv into my project.

Scenario 1:

- Start page: session file name AAA
- Cart was empty, I added item and do purchasing, after page redirected from E-xact (payment successfully). All page's sessions were gone. Session file BBB was created and of course it was empty.
- On session file BBB, logged in again, go back to cart and do purchasing again for the item that I already added before and it was successful.

Scenario 2:

- On session file BBB, I did adding cart, payment again as same as Scenario 1. It was created session file CCC and went back the problem as Scenario 1.

I tried: (but the issues still happens)

- Truncate my databases.
- Clear all session's files
- Installing new project
- Change session.gc_maxlifetime 1440 to session.gc_maxlifetime 3600
- Comment phpdotenv
- Comment all $this->session->destroy().
- Send and get session back by session ID:

```
logger("SSID before: ".$this->session->getId(), 0);
$ssId = $this->request->getQuery("ssId");
session_id($ssId);
session_start();
logger("SSID after: ".$this->session->getId(), 0);

// Log info
[INFO][2020/08/24 10:27:22 AM]: SSID before: 82119875f4e94fbf4d34a5d14515c5c9
[INFO][2020/08/24 10:27:22 AM]: SSID after: 8229b3e8e644c5a3b7a8c89ab0a9c778
[INFO][2020/08/24 10:27:49 AM]: SSID before: 82119875f4e94fbf4d34a5d14515c5c9
[INFO][2020/08/24 10:27:49 AM]: SSID after: 82119875f4e94fbf4d34a5d14515c5c9
```

My initial script for session

```
$di->setShared('session', function () {
    $session = new SessionAdapter();
    $session->start();
    return $session;
});
```

I know that I am facing this issue because Phalcon created new session file after redirecting from another page. However, I din't know how and when does Phalcon framework create new session file?

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I don't believe Phalcon creates or manages sessions - it ties into PHP's built-in session management.  All Phalcon does is create some easier-to-use wrappers around the functionality.  Try swapping out all the Phalcon session code with built-in calls and see if the problem persists.  My guess is this is an issue with the process, not with Phalcon.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, It was FAVICON !!!

I fixed this issue after reading this post [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953536/randomly-losing-session-variables-only-in-google-chrome-url-rewriting)

All I need to do are:

- Check favicon.ico link works,
- And add this line to .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^favicon.ico$ favicon.ico [L]
```

In my special case, my former coworker wrote this favicons link looks like this:

```
<link rel="icon" href="{{ image_url }}/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

I have to changed it to

```
<link rel="icon" href="/public/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

Don't forget CTRL + SHIFT + F5 to refresh page.